# Add Custom Data to OpenLayers Plugin for QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Is there a way to add custom data to the OpenLayers plugin for QGIS?  I have tiled data using Map Tiler, which has produced my zoom levels, and an OpenLayers.html.  I am hosting it internally on our servers, and I would like to access it from the OpenLayers plugin.

Thoughts on where to start?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by copying the osm.html file in

```
username/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/html
```

as well as adding the needed lines in

```
username/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_plugin.py
```

You can find a detailed workflow in my answer here:

[Easiest way to create historical street maps using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69907/easiest-way-to-create-historical-street-maps-using-qgis)

Only disadvantage is that the next update of the plugin will delete your edits

Another possibility is the Tile Layer plugin.