# How to add HERE maps to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, wms, here-maps

I am trying to add an interactive map HERE to my ArcMap? I am using ArcGIS 10 and the path I have been following so far is through "Add WMS Server" (Catalog -> GIS Servers -> Add WMS Server). Unfortunately, this is not  working for me. The way I see it, this can have two reasons:

1. Did I do something wrong here ?
2. This is not the way to go.

In case of the former, what is that I am doing wrong?

I am using the AppID and AppCode from my HERE developer account. I have tried different things for the URL. The last one I tried was simply https://www.here.com/?map=51.54916,5.64706,10,normal (I was running out of ideas). Usually it tells me there is a connection error.

[image: Add WMS Server]

In case of option 2, that this isn't the way to go, what should I do to display HERE maps in ArcMap? It surely isn't offered through Add Basemap/ArcGIS Online.

In QGIS it is possible to add HERE maps in multiple ways. See this post: [HERE background maps in QGIS possible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/here-background-maps-in-qgis-possible)
I hope there is a way around to get it fix in ArcMap as well.

I think that there is a third option, and that it isn't possible at all, period. But I sure hope somebody can tell me how I can get it done.

Comment: You might want to look into [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/here-background-maps-in-qgis-possible) question. Perhaps you are flexible and you can work with QGIS. If not, it might still give you a hint on how to implement it in ArcGIS (if possible).

Comment: Thanks, but that link is already in my question. In fact, the QGIS question also came from me :)

Comment: It just came to my mind and I quickly copied the link... should have checked that :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**

I'm not sure you can add here.com using that dialog, it's specifically for OGC Web Map Services (WMS), but Here.com isn't as far as I can tell an OGC WMS.

**Option 2**

here.com exposes both a [JavaScript API](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis) and a [REST API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis), so you should be able to do something programmatically.

Comment: I agree, there isn't a mention of a WMS server anywhere I saw on their site

Comment: @Branco Agreed, there isn't. I did find some references online however, where here.com was referred to as a WMS and that's why I gave it a try. Now my question remains if there is another way to display the data in ArcMap. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I suppose in semantic sense it is a web map service, so I should have been more precise and say an OGC WMS.

Comment: It is possible that they restrict what can be seen outside of their site.  You might have some luck checking into the details of their developers site.  You might be able to request free tiles from their site (similar to OSM and Open Mapquest), but they you would need to find a way to turn it into a 'service' that ArcMap can read in.

Comment: It is possible to display the data in FME Data Inspector and QGIS, so it is definitely possible to use it outside of the HERE website. I have gone through the whole developers site twice (at least that's how it feels :)) but I haven't found any leads.

Comment: @nmtoken I was thinking that something programmatically should be possible, but I lack the skills to create something like it so I was hoping somebody would have an on the shelf solution.

Comment: Going back to option 1, as you can access it in QGIS by using the GDAL WMS mini driver, perhaps you could set up some sort of proxy by say using MapServer to use the GDAL input as the data source to a local WMS then map to that WMS.  I have a feeling that this should work, but I'm not sure what the performance hit might be.

Answer (score 1):

See this page. Here Satellite image Tiles

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fab611dbcefe4e3cac3821da6ca36777

Comment: The page linked to doesn't explain how to do it. At the moment this appears to be a link only answer, and as such is likely to be deleted.  You should at least give some explanation of the link, and how following it will answer the question

Answer (score 0):

A commercial product is also available.
https://www.geomer.de/produkte/software/her-o-gis.html