# Adding HERE map to ArcGIS Desktop using WMTS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, wmts, here-maps

I need here maps on ArcGIS Desktop so can ı do it using WMTS or API?

I tried add wmts services with Portable Basemap but did not work

I searched wms or wmts services for here map but ı did not find it

I am using Arcgis version 10.4.1

Comment: Are you trying to do this using ArcGIS Desktop or the ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Comment: I am using arcmap for gis. How can i add javascript

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you using?  You have a tag for 10.0 but do not mention that version in the body of your question.

Comment: Arcgis version 10.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use JavaScript in ArcGIS for Desktop.

There doesn't seem to be a WMTS or WMS service available for HERE maps, so an alternative would be to install the ArcBrutile add-on: https://github.com/ArcBruTile/ArcBruTile/ . It should support Here, according to its project page.

See also: [How to add HERE maps to ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139432/how-to-add-here-maps-to-arcmap)

Comment: Arcbrutile version 0.7 not have heremap, Arcbrutile 0.9 support heremap but I havent it.