# Why do labels in exports using HERE tiles appear tiny?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, here-maps

I am trying to export images from the QGIS print composer, the exported image has a basemap that is loaded from an XML file following [this questions method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/here-background-maps-in-qgis-possible). The export doesn't look at all like the image I see in the print composer see below and I'm trying to understand why.

What I'm trying to do is simply make a decent looking map without obvious tiling with readable labels. Perhaps I have to use a satellite only image and remake with my own labels. The map is a HERE nokia hybrid map

This is a jpeg at 150 dpi, note the tiny labels in comparison to the screenshot at the bottom
[image: This is a jpeg at 150 dpi].

This is a png export at 300 dpi, which is standard for the print composer, note the labels, and tiles. 
[image: this is a png at 300dpi which is standard print composer]

Finally, this is a screenshot of the map as it looks in the print composer with the labels readable at this zoom scale. 
[image: This is a screenshot of the map as it looks in the print composer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What seems to happen is that the composer tries to print a larger map on a smaller area to go from 72dpi (assumed screen resolution) to 150/300dpi. It even looks like it zooms out automatically...

Try adding &[ppi=320](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/resource-aerial-basetile.html) as a URL parameter to the server URL. That should scale up the labels enough for your print resolution.

Comment: thanks,  `<ServerUrl>https://1.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/hybrid.day/${z}/${x}/${y}/256/png8?app_id=dEKUTzncoRbyC15LuFgf&amp;app_code=6bk41pC1aTyaSrPVuTbEGg</ServerUrl>` this is the xml i'm using. Any ideas where the `&ppi=320` should go?

Comment: Just right at the end, the same way you add app_id and and app_code: `<ServerUrl>https://1.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/hy‌​brid.day/${z}/${x}/${y}/256/png8?app_id=dEKUTzncoRbyC15LuFgf&amp;app_code=6bk41pC‌​1aTyaSrPVuTbEGg&amp;ppi=320</ServerUrl>`

Comment: Great stuff, it works like a charm depending on dpi specifications