# Fixing tiny microscopic Map font size on UHD?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

QGIS 3.0
Added OSM layer via QuickMap services. This is what I see on my UHD display:

[image]

I understand that tile server just seeds tiles and we don't have any control over tiles generation. But why not to scale things if you're on UHD display?

I would expect QGIS to handle this by itself, we're at the 2nd quarter of 2019 after all.

Any ideas how to get it working?

It's impossible to work with maps in such circumstances.

Comment: related questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194953/why-do-labels-in-exports-using-here-tiles-appear-tiny, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/qgis-2-18-quickmapservices-basemap-labels-shrink-when-exported-to-pdf-from-print

Comment: Those tiles are intended for lower-resolution monitors, so the labels are out of proportion with the imagery on your screen. You can manually force QGIS to use a lower-resolution tile, or you can find a source of high-resolution tiles (sometimes called retina), or you can use un-labelled tiles and add labels manually or add a different, label-only basemap.