# Capturing Building level information (name and street names) from Basemap Using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, basemap, here-maps, malaysia

I wanted to capture House number and street number of Malaysia. I Found that Heremaps  streets and Open route services have proper House numbers and street names to capture like this in the below image

[image]

Can we take those services to QGIS as basemaps? Is there any WMS  or any services that can help to capture the information? Is there any plugin that can help you to download the information from WMS?

I have tried this GDAL for Heremaps  [Heremaps as basemap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/here-background-maps-in-qgis-possible), but i am unable to add the Heremaps Terrain to QGIS. It would be very helpful if i can add the heremaps Terrain as it is to the QGIS as a basemap.

Answer (score 1):

A WMS usually only displays a raster background. If the provider has enabled it, you can get additional information per mouseclick. Heremaps does not seem to do that, Openrouteservice neither.

You can however download address data from OpenStreetMap, if someone has added it to the map. There is however not much adress information available for Malaysia.

Comment: What my plan is, creating POINT data at that particular building foot prints and do reverse geocoding or adding attributes to the information. I just need WMS as basemap in QGIS. showing Building number and street names and all as it is showing in maps. I have checked this question [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/here-background-maps-in-qgis-possible)  . Can some one tell where i could save that XML document and how we can proceed to load Heremaps ?

Comment: Provided you have an app ID and code, just copy the xml from the given answer and paste it in a new empty file on your computer. Name the file `Here.xml` and continue as explained. Or edit the TileLayer plugin file as explained.