# Adding Here WeGo Satellite imagery to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, imagery

Here WeGo has more updated imagery for Cambodia than Google.  I would like to add the WeGo image tile to QGIS.  I have followed the instructions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138255/here-background-maps-in-qgis-possible) and can add the WeGo street layers to my map of Cambodia.

I have followed [this link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/example-satellite-map.html) to add satellite imagery.  I took the original XML file posted in the link and altered the URL but used the same key as the street layer version of the XML.
Here is a screen grab of how/where I got the app ID and app key.

[image]

This resulted in a layer that repeats a tile of southern Spain.  I am unaware of how to alter my XML code to get the WeGo image tile to draw for southern Cambodia.

How can I alter the code to get WeGo imagery to draw in QGIS?

```
<GDAL_WMS>
<Service name="TMS">
<ServerUrl>https://2.aerial.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/5/15/12/256/png8?app_id=tEu0WBZmhFgA0aSvAJfM&amp;app_code=V32dyBBowZHxPHGMUTQH2g</ServerUrl>
</Service>
<DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>

<TileLevel>20</TileLevel>
<TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
<TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
<YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
</DataWindow>
<Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
<BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
<BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
<BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
<Cache />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there may be an issue with your app_code and app_id.

I was able to add that service as an XYZ Tile in QGIS using my App_id/App_code, but not with yours. Is yours restricted to a domain?

[image]

And: 
[image]

If you are adding this as an XYZ Tile, you have to put the z,x,y parameters in place of actual values:

`https://2.aerial.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/5/15/12/256/png8?app_id=tEu0WBZmhFgA0aSvAJfM&app_code=V32dyBBowZHxPHGMUTQH2g`

becomes:

`https://2.aerial.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8?app_id=tEu0WBZmhFgA0aSvAJfM&app_code=V32dyBBowZHxPHGMUTQH2g`

Comment: Thanks @Jay Cummins!  Using the browser panel in QGIS 2.18 I was able to add a new connection using the line above.  I can now see the Here map imagery in QGIS.